# Grid game board

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to quad my board game, I must create coordinates, but i don't know how to do. I need your help !! Thanks

```
var mapArray = [ 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
];

function drawMap() {
var col = [];
var table = document.createElement("table");
for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
if (parseInt(mapArray[i][j]) == 0) {
$('#canvas').append('<div class="grass"></div>');
}
if (parseInt(mapArray[i][j]) == 1) {
$('#canvas').append('<div class="wall"></div>'); 
}}}}
$('document').ready(function() {
drawMap();
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] for help clarifying this question.

Comment: btw, an (integer) number does not need to be parsed as integer.

Comment: `quad my board game` ... make it 4 times bigger?

Comment: do you want a table or a canvas for the game?

Comment: I need to make a canvas 10X10, after I must to add weapons and characters on it. I need to draw gridlines => be able to retrieve (or display) the coordinates of each box in order to have a good base

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to read up on some canvas manipulation using JavaScript. Example on how to draw lines and what not. But here you go.

I have the below function which draws the grid

```
function drawGrid(w, h, canvas, ctx, spacing) {
  canvas.width  = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.35)';
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;

  for (var x=0; x<=w; x+=spacing) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, h);
   }

    for (var y=0;y<=h;y+=spacing) {
        ctx.moveTo(0, y);
        ctx.lineTo(w, y);
    }
  ctx.stroke();
};
```

Now to explain the above: I pass the width of the canvas, the height of the canvas, the canvas element, the context of the canvas and then the spacing of the grid (example: 16px) I then do a for loop to create the lines and the. I draw them.

The next part of your question is returning the cell the mouse is in. It can be done by the following code - which is two functions for simplicity

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function getGridLocation(posX, posY, gridsize)
{
  var cellRow = Math.floor(posY / gridsize);
  var cellColumn = Math.floor(posX / gridsize);

  return {
    row: cellRow,
    column: cellColumn
 };
}
```

So above is first to get the mouse co-ordinates and then I use the second function which gets passed the mouse coordinates and then divides them by each cell of the grid and floors the number.

Below is how to get mouse position per cell.

```
gridCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    var mousePos = getMousePos(gridCanvas, evt);
    var gridLocation = getGridLocation(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 64);
    //alert("Row: " + gridLocation.row + " Column: " + gridLocation.column);
  }, false);
```

Comment: Nice to see you helping other users. Good on you!

Comment: Thank you! Ive lurked for long enough, feels like I should give an input after your help yesterday! Paying it forward!

Comment: Thank you Lucy !!, I 'm beginner so I have some difficulties to insert the grass and walls in your code...If you know a tuto to recommend me, that would be great !

Comment: I can definitely steer you in there right direction. If you have a 10x10 grid you can paint to the canvas using a for loop. As it seems like you’re making a game in HTML5 you will definitely need canvas. I recommend looking at phaserJS for game development examples and even a YouTube video on canvas manipulation. How to get things to follow a mouse etc. Get the basics down pat - and move over to the more advanced stuff like making this game. If you have any questions feel free to ask. I’ll be happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
 const board = [ 
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
];

const markup = board.map(row => row.map(col => `<span class="field ${col === 0 ? "grass" : "wall"}"></span>` ).join("")).join("<span class='clear'></span>");

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = markup;
```

```css
.field {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}

.grass {
  background: green;
}

.wall {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
```